# Access layout service response sitecore.context object in Layout.JS file

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk, sitecore-react

In JSS react how to access the layout service response object `sitecore.context` in src/Layout.js.

If you look at src/Layout.js file, In default we can access only `sitecore.route` fields but not `sitecore.context`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this in one way.

Go to `\src\RouteHandler.js` here `sitecore.context` will be available.

Change the line like below, (This will pass context object to layout)

```
// Original line
return <Layout route={layoutData.route} />;
// Change this line
return <Layout route={layoutData.route} sitecoreContext={this.props.sitecoreContext} />;
```

Goto `\src\Layout.js`, change the line below

```
// Original line
const Layout = ({ route }) => {
// Change this line
const Layout = ({ sitecoreContext, route }) => {
```

We can access the `sitecoreContext` object now.

Answer (score 1):

We can get `Sitecore context` using by importing `sitecore-jss-react` on the component

```
import { withSitecoreContext } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';
```

and use this service to access context item as follows:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => <div>Page editing: {props.sitecoreContext.pageEditing}</div>;
// wrap MyComponent in the HOC (note the double function invocation - important)
export default withSitecoreContext()(MyComponent);
```

You can get more detail from [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/accessing-the-sitecore-context-data-in-a-react-component.html)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The question is accessed in layout.js file, not in the component. Above snippet not working at layout.js